# RSpec x Capybara モーダルは表示されているが見つけてくれない

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

ユーザー削除ボタンを押した時のモーダルの表示内容をテストしたいのですが
以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
it "他のユーザーを削除できること" do
  visit user_path(I18n.locale, other_user)
  page.dismiss_confirm(I18n.t("users.show.このユーザーを完全に削除します。本当によろしいですか？")) do
    find(".card-link.delete-user").click # 「アカウントを削除」をクリック
  end
end
```

```
Failure/Error:
   page.dismiss_confirm(I18n.t("users.show.このユーザーを完全に削除します。本当によろしいですか？")) do
     find(".card-link.delete-user").click
   end
 
 Capybara::ModalNotFound:
   Unable to find modal dialog with Xóa bỏ người dùng này. Bạn có chắc bạn muốn làm điều này?
```

ただ、スクショを見るとモーダルは表示されていて、注意喚起の文言も一致しておりました。

### 試したこと

・capybara-webkit　をbundle install
・もともと、expect(page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text).to eq I18n.t〜...
　でテストを書いていた際は次のエラーが出ておりました。

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchAlertError:
   no such alert
     (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

### コード

```
<%= link_to "アカウントを削除", user_path(@user), method: :delete, class: "card-link delete-user",
                                            data: { confirm: t(".このユーザーを完全に削除します。本当によろしいですか？") }, title: t(".削除確認") %>
```

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "byebug", platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "pry-byebug"
  gem "pry-doc"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.9"
  gem "factory_bot_rails", "~> 4.11"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "show_me_the_cookies"
  gem "faker", :git => "https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker.git", :branch => "master"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
  gem "capybara-webkit"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require "capybara/rspec"
require "database_cleaner"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  
end
```

どなたか、解決方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

### 更新 2020.10.16

以下で対応することにしました。
先頭行をコメントアウトするときちんとエラーになるので、これでいいかなと思います。

```
find(".card-link.delete-user").click # 「アカウントを削除」をクリック
within ".modal-content" do
  expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("users.show.削除確認")
  expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("users.show.このユーザーを完全に削除します。本当によろしいですか？")
  expect { click_button "Confirm" }.to change { User.count }.by(-1)
end
```

Comment: 追記された内容が解決策の一つであるなら、質問文に直接書いてしまうのではなく、個別の自己回答として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find modal dialog with Xóa bỏ người dùng này. Bạn có chắc bạn muốn làm điều này?

これが日本語じゃないのが気になりました。

ひとまず、dismiss_confirmは第一引数を省略できるようでした ( https://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/3.33.0/Capybara/Session#dismiss_confirm-instance_method ) ので、

```rb
it "他のユーザーを削除できること" do
  visit user_path(I18n.locale, other_user)
  page.dismiss_confirm do
    find(".card-link.delete-user").click # 「アカウントを削除」をクリック
  end
end
```

を試してみるのはどうでしょう？

Comment: Capybara::ModalNotFound: Unable to find modal dialog が発生してしまいました。
ロケールを日本語に変えてみても同様のエラーになったため、そもそもの設定や環境におかしな点がないか探って見ようと思います。m(_ _)m